# Highlight rows in a table with Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm preprocessing some data that users upload, and I want to tell them if any lines of the data are invalid.  I figured it'd make sense to check each line, if there are errors add that line number to a hashset of errorlines, then when outputting check if the current index is in the hashset, and highlight that row.

Here's the relevant jsp:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <s:iterator value="prettyNames">
                <th><s:property /></th>
            </s:iterator>
        </tr>
        <s:iterator value="importList" status="stat">
            <tr class="class="${lineErrors.contains(%{#stat.index}) ? 'highlight' : ''}"">
                <s:iterator>
                    <td><s:property /></td>
                </s:iterator>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
```

Where highlight sets the background color red.  However I get a warning in Eclipse saying ""test" does not support runtime 
 expressions" and the page returns a 500 error, "According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute test does not accept any expressions".

What is the correct way to highlight arbitrary lines in a table?

Comment: jonathan.cone's answer should be correct. But you need to ensure that `public Set<Integer> getLineErrors() {}` is exist in action class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this error is because you're trying to evaluate a standard JSP EL expression inside of a Struts2 tag attribute, in this case "test".  You need to use the OGNL notation with S2 tags, like so (assuming lineErrors resolves against the ValueStack):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <s:iterator value="prettyNames">
            <th><s:property /></th>
        </s:iterator>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="importList" status="stat">
        <s:if test="%{lineErrors.contains(#stat.index)}">
            <tr class="highlight">
                <s:iterator>
                    <td><s:property /></td>
                </s:iterator>
            </tr>
        </s:if>
        <s:else>
            <tr>
                <s:iterator>
                    <td><s:property /></td>
                </s:iterator>
            </tr>           
        </s:else>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Of course the shorter way would be something like this, where you nest the S2 property tag inside the class attribute, but this is less readable:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <s:iterator value="prettyNames">
            <th><s:property /></th>
        </s:iterator>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="importList" status="stat">
        <tr class="<s:property value='%{lineErrors.contains(#stat.index) ? "highlight" : ""}' />">
            <s:iterator>
                <td><s:property /></td>
            </s:iterator>
        </tr>           
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Comment: The result of this is the line `<tr class="class="%{lineErrors.contains(#stat.index) : 'highlight' : ''}">` in the served page source.  It doesn't get evaluated.

Comment: OGNL expressions won't evaluate outside of Struts2 tag attributes.  Update your source code example with what you're trying and I will post a more complete example.  Right now, your example shows "<tr class="class="" which is obviously not valid.

Comment: Ok, Java Drinker's answer suggested they could.  What's posted in my question is the JSP I'm currently trying.

Comment: And you have a collection called lineErrors on your S2 action with a getter titled getLineErrors?

Comment: Not familiar with struts, so I don't know that you can do method calls like contains etc in EL. If this is possible, then great. Otherwise, might be worth doing the necessary work at the backing bean level, and set a property on the stat object (stat.flag or stat.error or something) and just check that. Sometimes its easy to get carried away with doing logic in EL

Comment: @dimo414, then either of the approaches I updated the comment with should work.

Comment: There is a very good example of building a table with alternating rows by using the odd and even properties from the status object of the iterator: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/iterator.html

Comment: I think your answer is worked just fine, but the `%{}` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it is not valid XHTML. You cannot have the `<tr>` tag started where ever you please. I would re-write this as something like

```
<tr class="${lineErrors.contains(%{#stat.index}) ? 'highlight' : ''}">
    <!--whatever-->
</tr>
```

That's what I would do in something like Facelets, so probably the EL works the same way in struts. I'm not sure I understand the `%{#...` maddness that's happening

Comment: Ok thanks, didn't know you could do a ternary operator in jsp.  Unrelated to my problem though, since changing the conditional to, for instance, `true` works just fine.  I don't understand the `%{#` madness either, I'm just learning this :P

Comment: Prefix # to a variable if it is not from your action. %{expression} denotes expression as an OGNL expression, most struts2 tags assume this to be the case and do not need expressions to be wrapped in %{}.